# gulp-sequence not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have implementing gulp task in the project.
I have installed gulp-assests-version-replace to make version control file of css file.

Now I want to run above task after creating the app.css. It runs before creating the app.css, so version control file cannot be created.

Below is the gulp-file for running the gulp tasks.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var changed      = require('gulp-changed');
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var del          = require('del');
var gulpif       = require('gulp-if');
var gutil        = require('gulp-util');
var imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin');
var jshint       = require('gulp-jshint');
var notify       = require('gulp-notify');
var plumber      = require('gulp-plumber');
var rename       = require('gulp-rename');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var assetsVersionReplace = require('gulp-assets-version-replace');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');


var path = {
    assets: 'skin/frontend/custom_theme/default/'
};

var config = {
    tasks: {
        css: {
            autoprefixerOptions: {
                // For "browserslist" see "package.json"
                cascade: false,
                supports: false // See: https://github.com/filamentgroup/select-css/issues/17
            },
            dest: path.assets + 'css/build',
            sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
            },
            src: path.assets + 'css/src/**/*.scss'
        },
        version: {
            autoprefixerOptions: {
                // For "browserslist" see "package.json"
                cascade: false,
                supports: false // See: https://github.com/filamentgroup/select-css/issues/17
            },
            dest: path.assets + 'css/build',
            sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
            },
            src: path.assets + 'css/build/app.css'
        }
    }
}

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('css');
    gulp.start('assetsVersionReplace');
});

    gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([
        path.assets + 'css/build',
        path.assets + 'js/build',
        path.assets + 'js/min',
        path.assets + 'img/build'
    ]);
});
gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.tasks.css.src)
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: reportError
        }))
        .pipe(sass(config.tasks.css.sassOptions))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(config.tasks.css.autoprefixerOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tasks.css.dest));
});

gulp.task('assetsVersionReplace', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.tasks.version.src)
    .pipe(assetsVersionReplace({
      replaceTemplateList: [
        'app/design/frotend/custom_theme/default/template/page/head.phtml'
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tasks.version.dest))
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    // Run "default" immediately
    gulp.start('default');

    // CSS
    gulp.watch(config.tasks.css.src, ['css']);
    gulp.watch(config.tasks.version.src,              ['assetsVersionReplace']);
});
```

How can I run assetsVersionReplace task after creating the css (or after runnung 'CSS' task)?

Answer (score 0):

Either change

```
gulp.task('assetsVersionReplace', function () {
```

to

```
gulp.task('assetsVersionReplace', ['css'], function () {
```

or, if that isn't an option, add a helper task

```
gulp.task('assetsVersionReplaceAfterCss', ['css'], function () {
    gulp.start('assetsVersionReplace');
}
```

and use that instead

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use gulp series.

```
gulp.task('default',
    gulp.series(
       'css',
       'assetsVersionReplace'
    )
);
```

Comment: gulp.series is gulp4.0 only - still in beta!